# Angular Form Submit shall be disabled but still show error when clicked

Tags: angular, forms, typescript

My intention is to create a form in Angular. The submit button shall be disabled as long as !f.valid (the form is not valid). As soon as the user clicks the button though, the background-color of all invalid input shall change. Additionally a alert below the form shall be displayed.

So far I've also tried to disable the button manually in typescript and change the background-color via [class.myClass]="!f.valid" - but this changes the background-color from the beginning, since the form wasn't touched yet and hence is still invalid.

In conclusion, the form shall only change the background-color of invalid inputs, if the submit button has been clicked. Anyways, the submit button itself shall not submit any data until every required input field is valid.

My HTML Form:

```
<form class="w-50 mb-5 mt-5" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" ngModel required>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" placeholder="Future Family Name" ngModel required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail" ngModel email required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="package" placeholder="Please choose a package from the selection above!" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedPackage" required readonly>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="date" name="date" placeholder="When is your wedding?" class="form-control" ngModel required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="text" rows="4" placeholder="Your message.." ngModel></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="w-100 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 text-center">
            <span class="alert-info-display-none">Please fill in the required fields above.</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 text-center mt-2" (click)="check(f)">
            <button type="submit" [disabled]="!f.valid">Send</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Won't help, but anyways; Typescript:

```
@Input() selectedDiv: number;
  selectedPackage: string;

  onSubmit(form: NgForm): void {
    console.log(form);
  }

  changePackageInfo(): void {
    if (this.selectedDiv === 0) {
      this.selectedPackage = '';
    }
    if (this.selectedDiv === 1) {
      this.selectedPackage = 'You\'ve chosen Package One';
    }
    if (this.selectedDiv === 2) {
      this.selectedPackage = 'You\'ve chosen Package Two';
    }
    if (this.selectedDiv === 3) {
      this.selectedPackage = 'You\'ve chosen Package Three';
    }
  }

  public ngOnChanges(changes) {
    if ('selectedDiv' in changes) {
      this.changePackageInfo();
      }
    }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.changePackageInfo();
  }
```

Comment: As far as I understood you want the button to be clickable but to only submit if the form is valid otherwise show errors messages? if so, you can let the button always submit (calling the onSubmit function) and within the onSubmit function you submit if the form is valid otherwise change the background and show the alert ...etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a Boolean variable to keep track of form state. Set this variable only on form submit. And use this variable on template to control the visibilty of Errors.

> In Component :

```
  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.showError = form.invalid;
    if(form.invalid) return;
    // continue submission logic here.
  }
```

> Corresponding Template usage

```
<div>
    <label for="email">
    <span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">*</span>
      Email
    </label>
    <input 
        id="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="emailText" 
        required #email="ngModel"
        [ngStyle]="{'background-color':showError && email.invalid ? 'red': ''}">
  </div>
```

You can check the working code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4rdxbn?embed=1&file=src/app/hello.component.html)